# Nutch 2.3 not able to parse a URL which is correctly parsed through parsechecker

Tags: apache, nutch, apache-tika, html-parser

I am experimenting with Apache Nutch 2.3.

When I ran the parse command for the URL http://comptuergodzilla.blogspot.com Nutch parse the content correctly. I mean I get all the outlinks and content in `ol` and `p` column family respectively.

But when I did the same for URL http://goal.com/en-india it was not able to parse the site outlinks and content.

What makes me scratch my head is after running parsechecker command for URL http://www.goal.com/en-india I get all the parsed contents and outlinks.

Regarding above my questions are:

```
 i. Why parse command is not working? It should work if parsechecker is parsing the URL correctly.
 ii. Do I have to build the separate HTMLParser plugin for achieving above.
```